# How to use a pre-set method in a function? (expand.grid)

Tags: r

I want to scale my script using a conditional value as method in a function rather than the actual method. How do I get the function to recognize the value as a method?

This is for R on RStudio 1.1.463.

I want to reproduce this:

```r
rooster=c("Bob","Bill","Joe")
head(expand.grid("Task 1" = rooster, "Task 2" = rooster, "Task 3" = rooster))
```

I'm not certain of the way to explain it but basically R understands that when I write "rooster" it should go and fetch the value rooster.

I was hoping the same logic would apply to the whole method of the function and that this would work

```r
rooster=c("Bob","Bill","Joe")
nb<-3
z<-as.factor(paste(paste('"Task ',1:nb,'" = rooster',sep=""),collapse=", "))
z
```

So value z reproduces exactly the method presented above. Namely, ""Task 1" = rooster, "Task 2" = rooster, "Task 3" = rooster)"

```r
expand.grid(z)
```

Alas clearly R does not understands that this is meant to be a method and not a mere value (I've tried as.vector instead of as.factor but to no avail)

So I was expecting this:

```r
> expand.grid("Task 1" = rooster, "Task 2" = rooster, "Task 3" = rooster)
Task 1 Task 2 Task 3
1     Bob    Bob    Bob
2    Bill    Bob    Bob
3     Joe    Bob    Bob
4     Bob   Bill    Bob
5    Bill   Bill    Bob
...
```

And instead I'm saddled with that:

```r
> expand.grid(z)
Var1
1 "Task 1" = rooster, "Task 2" = rooster, "Task 3" = rooster
```

Any idea how to overcome that issue?

Comment: `n = 3; setNames(expand.grid(replicate(n, rooster, simplify = FALSE)), paste0("Task", seq(n)))`

Comment: setNames!!! damn it!!! Thanks a buch, it works perfectly.